# How do I make my SVN repository look exactly like my working copy?

Tags: svn, netbeans, version-control, ubersvn

My SVN repository is filled with errors because I committed the cardinal sin of trying to camelcase one of my directories.

What I want is just to make my SVN repository (which I'm the only one using so I can do whatever to it) look exactly like my working copy and stop erroring out. I'm using uberSVN right now, and after hours and hours of trying I can't get it to work. Is there any way to get a tree view of my repository and edit it through there? Should I just delete the repository and start again from scratch?

Comment: Have you tried to rename the appropriate folders? (from Windows or Linux?)

Comment: Fresh working copy checkout from the server? Should help.

Comment: Hey guys, I did try editing it from Windows (and through netbeans), but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though Gilbert Le Blanc's answer was technically right, I actually used TortoiseSVN, which does have a Tree View where I could edit the repository. I was able to fix it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used uberSVN, but here's the general procedure for modifying a Subversion repository.

- Disconnect your working copy from Subversion.
- Rename your working copy main directory.
- Make whatever changes you need to make to the folder and file names of your Subversion repository.
- Check out a working copy from your Subversion repository.
- Make any changes to your new working copy modules manually by copying and pasting from your original, renamed working copy.
- Commit your working copy to Subversion.
- Delete your original, renamed working copy.